# removing white background after tracing a logo in illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I have a o that I traced. I removed the white background by selecting expand and clearing it. however, the white background is still in the test part of the logo. thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Could you maybe post a screenshot including your layer panel? I'm kinda confused - if you drew a logo in illustrator just delete the rest of the layers/objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metis' method (ticking 'Ignore White') works perfectly in this case (when the background color is white)...

But if the background isn't white (and you want to keep your colors) how to proceed?

Assuming a two color trace – this method will work no matter what the background color might be.

When you do your trace, open the Image Trace Panel (Window > Image Trace) set it up beforehand as 2 color:

[image: Two color trace]

Then hit the 'Trace' button followed by the 'Expand' button.

Now press the <kbd>A</kbd> key, and click on your background. Then go to Select > Same > Fill Color:

[image: Select menu]

And lastly, just press the <kbd>Del</kbd> key.

Done like dinner. Before and after:

[image: The Trumpster]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this method.  I am new in illustrator and so far have my experience has been with  white backgrounds. I  am sure I might work with images that have different backgrounds and I will definitely revert to the above method. Thank you once again

Comment: @Maha Hey, no problem... Glad I could help. If you found this answer useful please vote it up so I can get rid of the 666 already Lord have mercy

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but how do I vote it up?

Comment: To the left of the top of the answer: up and down arrows (to vote up/down) and a check in a diamond to accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

One of the easiest ways to handle this is to plan ahead.

On the **Image Trace Panel**, expand the `Advanced` options area...

Then tick `Ignore White`.

[image]

This will eliminate the tracing creating white objects, but it will still create counters or "holes" in other objects.

*Without* this option ticked, what happens is the trace creates an object, traces the counter/hole for the object, then creates the counter *and* a white shape above the counter. So you end up with the object **plus** white shapes where there are counters/holes. By ticking `Ignore White` none of those white shapes are created.

Then you can proceed to `Expand` and refine the elements after tracing.

Comment: oooh they're trying to auto-trace

Answer (score 0):

After expanding the white background might still be attached in pieces. Sometimes after tracing a circular object I have to delete 4 corners of white background.

Expand > Ungroup > Delete everything you don't want > Regroup what's left

Comment: I have tried ungrouping and deleting the fill in the text, but it becomes one solid car like the O for instance

Comment: Oh, so you have a situation with an "O" where the middle part that is supposed to be cut out is actually a white shape?  You need to clip the middle shape out of the O. Select both the middle shape and the O and go into the Pathfinder window and use Minus Front.

Comment: Wow, it worked!!! I can't thank you enough! Thank you so much cause it drove me crazy the past 2 days reading everything about clipping the white background out and nothing worked in the text part! now I can proudly us my logo:)